# getting error in a defined class name when importing in interactive shell

Tags: python

I wrote following program

```
#! /usr/bin/python

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width=0;
        self.width=0;
    def setSize(self,size):
        self.width,self.height = size
    def getSize(self):
        return self.width,self.height
```

the program is named something.py
There are 2 ways to run this program

```
1) $bash:~/$  python
   >>>import something
```

and the other way is

```
2) python -i something.py
```

in the case of first method when I do a

```
>>>r=Rectangle()
```

I get error

```
 r=Rectangle()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Rectangle' is not defined
```

but when I go by the second method
and do a `>>>r=Rectangle()`
then I do not get any error.

I checked for the first method

```
>>> dir(some)
['Rectangle', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

so name Rectangle is defined so why am I getting the error here?

**update**

I wrote another program

```
#! /usr/bin/python

def checkIndex(key):
    if not isinstance(key, (int, long)): raise TypeError
    if key<0: raise IndexError

class ArithmeticSequence:
    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start      # Store the start value
        self.step = step        # Store the step value
        self.changed = {}       # No items have been modified
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        checkIndex(key)
        try: return self.changed[key]
        except KeyError:
            return self.start + key*self.step
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        checkIndex(key)
        self.changed[key] = value
```

if you type this program as another.py and do
`>>> import another`
and 
`>>>s=ArithmeticSequence(1,2)`

One does not gets the error that
ArithmeticSequence is not defined.....

Comment: About the update: there must be something else going on, you must have defined `ArithmeticSequence` in some way. I cannot reproduce what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

When you [import a module](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), the names defined in it are not automatically added to the global namespace.
You need to do:

```
import something
r = something.Rectangle()
```

or

```
from something import Rectangle
r = Rectangle()
```